# Illustrator - How to let one layer show through another

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

This seems like it should be easy, but since I'm new to Illustrator it's hard to describe what I mean without an example.

Basically, I have two layers. The bottom layer has a picture of a pig. The top layer has a one-color icon (black). I want the fill of the icon to be replaced with the image underneath it. So that instead of an icon of a piggy bank in just black it is an icon of a piggy bank that looks like the pig picture.

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi Englei, what you're looking for is Clipping Mask. See the question I marked this a duplicate of and it answers it for you or you could look up Clipping Mask on the Adobe Website.

Comment: @Ryan that question is about Illustrator not Photoshop. (I know the screenshot is from Illustrator but the question asks for Photoshop)

Comment: I figured it out. A clipping Mask does work, but I had originally not been able to directly select the path. What I had to do was 1) not use "ignore white" when tracing the image 2) "Expand" the traced image 3) "Ungroup" it 4) Select the pig directly and use the Clipping Mask